# If $\partial_t f(x,t)=-f(x,t)$ and $f(x,0)= c \in [0,1]$, do we have $0 \leq f(x,t) \leq c$ for all $(x,t)$ with $t>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The question is as in the title.

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \times [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function.

Further suppose that $f(x,t)$ satisfies the following equation with the initial condition:
\begin{equation}
\partial_t f(x,t)=-f(x,t) \text{ and } f(x,0)=c \in [0,1]
\end{equation}
where $c$ is just a constant.

Then, is it inevitable that $0 \leq f(x,t) \leq c$ for all $(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times [0,\infty)$?

I find it qualitatively plausible from the equation itself, but cannot justify my guess systematically. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Why not just solve the equation? It's an ODE by the way.